# Bootstrap responsive video but with max-width AND centered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

To make a responsive 4x3 video embed for YouTube videos, the Bootstrap site says do this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

But I want the video to have a max-width of 400px.  So I defined a class:

```
.youtube {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

I tried this and it works:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

But for the life of me I cannot make this max-width (yet responsive below that max) iframe centered.  I've already tried adding `.center-block` to `.embed-responsive` and to `.embed-responsive-item`, but it does nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your video div surrounded by a column and a row?  If so what size are they?  Try making a working example of your issue in jsfiddle so that it's easier to see why it's not working.

Comment: Yes! Doing so now. Thanks. One moment …

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this one all morning. My vids are dynamic, so can't be sure they're 4x3. My Bootstrap 4/JQuery solution

Html:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-6 text-center">
    <!-- this code is in a foreach loop, hence @item.Link -->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="@item.Link"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
function resizeIframes() {
  var $allVideos = $('iframe');

  $allVideos.each(function () {
    $(this)
        .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

        // and remove the hard coded width/height
        .removeAttr('height')
        .removeAttr('width');
  });

  // When the window is resized
  $(window).resize(function () {
    // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
    $allVideos.each(function () {
        var newWidth = $(this).parent().width();

        var $el = $(this);
        $el
            .width(newWidth)
            .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));
    });

    // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
  }).resize();
}

resizeIframes();
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to make a demo in jsfiddle but it was producing results different from my browser. After four hours, I found a solution. In order to make an iframe both centered AND responsive, add `.text-center` to the immediate container div and make the position of the iframe element relative:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 text-center">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here’s the `.youtube` class:

```
.youtube {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
  position: relative !important;
}
```

The full HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<main class="col-sm-8 col-main">
<article class="post-main ">
<section>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 col--12 text-center">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KPZ8HHRR1A0"></iframe></div>
</section>
</article>
</main>
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```